# iOS - Cancel UIButton action if

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I've created a button that executes a series of items (not all shown in this code snippet to keep it brief). If my NSString (points) is greater than 96, I want the button action to cancel. **E.g.** Anything executed by tapping the button sendMessage should completely stop. I'm using the below code now, and it doesn't seem to stop the action from completing. Any idea why this might be?

**ViewController.h**

```
- (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *sendMessage;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
     - (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender {

            NSString *points;

            if (hour <= 1) {

                points = @"300";


            } else if (hour > 1 && hour < 9) {

                points = @"600";


            } else if (hour <= 9) {

                points = @"1000";

            } else if (hour < 9 && hour < 24) {

                points = @"1000";


            } else if (hour <= 48) {

                points = @"2000";

            } else if (hour > 48 && hour <= 72) {

                points = @"3000";

            } else if (hour > 72 && hour <= 96) {

                points = @"4000";

            } else if (hour > 96) {

                points = @"5000";

               self.sendMessage.enabled = NO;

              self.exceedsFive.hidden = NO;

            }

 [DIOSNode nodeSave:nodeData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Node did not save!");
        }];



    }
```

Comment: if `if (hour > 96)` you do not want DIOSNode Block to be executed right?

Comment: @Mr.Bista That is correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (hour > 96)` you do not want DIOSNode Block to be executed.

Then, do this, add a `return`:

```
else if (hour > 96) {

    points = @"5000";

    self.sendMessage.enabled = NO;

    return;
}
```

Comment: Adding a return seems to throw me an error on that last bracket?

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement:

```
If (points < 500) {
 [DIOSNode nodeSave:nodeData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Node did not save!");
        }];
```